# pages_sharing and pages_shared difference in ksm

Tags: virtualization, memory, kvm-virtualization

Can some one please help me understand this.

i am running kvm hosts with 5 vms on it.

These are ksm driver statistics

```
each page is 4KB

cat /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_shared     162221
cat /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_sharing    264281
cat /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_unshared   241483
```

Is "pages_sharing" total no of pages created by vms. and "pages_shared" is the number of pages that is found similar and merged together.

```
if that is true then why is  pages_sharing-pages_shared != pages_unshared


 264281-162221 != 241483
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pages_unshared` means just what it says: the pages could not be shared because they're unique.

`pages_shared` indicates how many pages are actually in use and being shared.

`pages_sharing` indicates how many pages the VMs think there are. If you didn't have KSM running, this is how many pages would actually be in use.

So, in your example, 264281 pages have been found to be shareable, and so they were merged into 162221 pages, while 241483 pages were not shareable. KSM saved you about 398 MB of memory.

Comment: can u tell me how did u get 398mb?

Comment: Sure: (264281 - 162221) * 4096 = 418037760. Divide by (1024 * 1024) and you get 398.67...

Comment: Your explanation about `pages_unshared` is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

See here https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/ksm.txt

```
pages_shared     - how many shared pages are being used
pages_sharing    - how many more sites are sharing them i.e. how much saved
pages_unshared   - how many pages unique but repeatedly checked for merging
```

So, you shouldn't substract pages_shared from pages_sharing. pages_sharing is saved memory!

Answer (score 0):

pages_sharing is the memory really saved: 264281*4096/1024/1024=1032MB

(264281 - 162221) * 4096 = 418037760. Divide by (1024 * 1024)= 398.67MB  is not  memory saved

Comment: Welcome on the ServerFault! Please, elabore more your answer - it is important, if not only these people can understand it, who can make this calculation also for themselfes :-)